# How to swap the column and row entries in R

Tags: r, data.table, data-wrangling

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 34, 99),
           class = c("sports", "", "music, sports", ""),
           hobby = c("knitting, music, sports", "", "", "music"))
> dat1
  id         class                   hobby
1  1        sports knitting, music, sports
2  2                                      
3 34 music, sports                        
4 99                                 music
```

I have the above dataset, `dat1`, where each row corresponds to a unique `id`. For each `id`, multiple inputs for either `class` or `hobby` are separated by a comma.

I would like to exchange the row and column of this dataset so that I get the following:

```
     input class hobby
1   sports 1, 34     1
2 knitting           1
3    music    34 1, 99
```

In this dataset, each row corresponds to a unique `input` from `dat1`. Now the `class` and `hobby` columns are storing the corresponding `id`s from `dat1`, each separated by a comma.

Is there a quick way to swap the row and columns like this in R?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution

##### Input

```
library(data.table)
dat1 <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 34, 99),
                   class = c("sports", "", "music, sports", ""),
                   hobby = c("knitting, music, sports", "", "", "music"))
dat1
#>    id         class                   hobby
#> 1:  1        sports knitting, music, sports
#> 2:  2                                      
#> 3: 34 music, sports                        
#> 4: 99                                 music
```

##### Dataprep

```
# in long format
dt_melted <- melt.data.table(dat1, id.vars = "id", variable.name = "type", value.name = "value")
dt_melted
#>    id  type                   value
#> 1:  1 class                  sports
#> 2:  2 class                        
#> 3: 34 class           music, sports
#> 4: 99 class                        
#> 5:  1 hobby knitting, music, sports
#> 6:  2 hobby                        
#> 7: 34 hobby                        
#> 8: 99 hobby                   music

# split values by comma
dt_splitted <- dt_melted[, .(input = unlist(data.table::tstrsplit(value, ","))), by = .(id, type)]
dt_splitted
#>    id  type    input
#> 1:  1 class   sports
#> 2: 34 class    music
#> 3: 34 class   sports
#> 4:  1 hobby knitting
#> 5:  1 hobby    music
#> 6:  1 hobby   sports
#> 7: 99 hobby    music
```

##### Last Step 1

```
# bring back to desired wide format
dt_casted <- dcast.data.table(dt_splitted, 
                              formula = "input ~ type",
                              value.var = "id",
                              fun.aggregate = paste, 
                              collapse = ", ")
dt_casted
#>       input class hobby
#> 1: knitting           1
#> 2:    music    34 1, 99
#> 3:   sports 1, 34     1
```

##### Last Step 2 (more verbose)

```
# combine ids by class/hobby
dt_splitted[, .(class = paste(id[type == "class"], collapse = ", "),
                hobby = paste(id[type == "hobby"], collapse = ", ")),
            by = .(input = trimws(input))]
#>       input class hobby
#> 1:   sports 1, 34     1
#> 2:    music    34 1, 99
#> 3: knitting           1
```

Answer (score 7):

Another `data.table` option using `dcast` + `melt`

```
dcast(
  melt(dat1[, lapply(.SD, strsplit, ", "), id], "id")[
    ,
    .(input = unlist(value)),
    .(id, variable)
  ], input ~ variable,
  value.var = "id",
  fun = toString
)
```

which gives

```
      input class hobby
1: knitting           1
2:    music    34 1, 99
3:   sports 1, 34     1
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick `tidyverse` way:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, values_to = "input") %>%
  separate_rows(input) %>% 
  filter(input != "") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "id", values_fn = toString)
```

```r
  input    class hobby
1 sports   1, 34 1    
2 knitting NA    1    
3 music    34    1, 99
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an (not that long) `tidyverse` option. The issue is that values for the future 'input` column are scattered into multiple columns and can contain several value into the same string.

First a `pivot_longer` to have all the future `input` into the same column:

```
dat2 = dat1 %>% pivot_longer(!id)
dat2
# A tibble: 8 x 3
     id name  value                    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>                    
1     1 class "sports"                 
2     1 hobby "knitting, music, sports"
3     2 class ""                       
4     2 hobby ""                       
5    34 class "music, sports"          
6    34 hobby ""                       
7    99 class ""                       
8    99 hobby "music"
```

Then the approach is to use the `stringr` package to split all the potential `input` values to then pivoting again to have all combination. Then filtering for the row having an `input` (`nchar(input)>0`).
Finally grouping by the `input` and `name` to paste the multiple `id` together `id = paste0(id, collapse = ",")`. And a last `pivot_wider` to have the data frame as desired:

```
cbind(dat2, str_split(str_remove_all(dat2$value, ","), " ", simplify = T)) %>%
  select(!value) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!c("id", "name"), names_to = "name_2", values_to = "input") %>% 
  select(!name_2) %>% 
  filter(nchar(input)>0) %>%
  group_by(input, name) %>% 
  summarise(id = paste0(id, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = id)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   input [3]
  input    hobby class
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1 knitting 1     NA   
2 music    1,99  34   
3 sports   1     1,34
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way, using dplyr, listing the values in the rows by calling `strsplit` then unnesting it, pivoting longer, back into pivot wider, to reverse the values.

```
library(dplyr)


dat1 |>
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(across(-id, ~ ifelse(nchar(.x), strsplit(.x, ", "), list("")))) |> 
  unnest(cols = -id) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = class:hobby) |> 
  filter(value != "") |> 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = value, names_from = name, values_from = id, 
              values_fn = \(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = " ,"))
```

```
  value    class hobby
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1 sports   1 ,34 1    
2 knitting NA    1    
3 music    34    1 ,99
```